# Require npm from different location

Tags: node.js

I have an application that needs to download npm packages at run-time. This has all worked fine, until we deployed the application as a **snap** to Ubuntu Core. This left the original app on a write protected area, and all run-time installed packages in the home directory (*~/home/use/node_modules*). And this was where the issues came :(

As I wanted to leave the application as is (as much as possible), I didn’t want to create my own *require* method, but just adding the path to the home directory when starting the application (using *process.env.NODE_PATH*).

The original application was then able to load the run-time installed packages, but those packages were not able to find other packages anywhere (not in it’s own node_modules folder, nor in the root).

I think I get the same issue (symptoms are the same) if I try to require a package from a different part of the disk, after added the path to the **process.env.NODE_PATH** variable.

**QUESTION:** Is there a better (working) way to solve this, without overriding the require method?

BTW.. I've tried using the *app-module-path* package as well, but with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried creating a symlink from the app's directory? The NPM packages are probably trying to use paths relative to your app because that's their context. If you create a symlink from `./node_modules` to `~/home/use/node_modules`, it may work.

Comment: Interesting idea, I'll get back to you on the progress